# how to prove that the formula for the volume center(centroid) is incorrect?

Tags: vector-analysis

Why the following derivation is incorrect?
Because
$$
\frac{1}{2}\nabla\left(\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}\right)=\vec{x}\cdot\nabla\vec{x}=\vec{x},
$$
the centroid/center $\vec{X^c}$ of the mass of a volume $V$ is by Gauss' Theorem:
$$
 \frac{1}{V}\iiint_V\vec{x}\,dV=\frac{1}{2V}\iiint_V\nabla\left(\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}\right)dV=\frac{1}{2V}\iint_S\left(\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}\right)\cdot\vec{n}\,dS
$$

However obviously the correct $\vec{X^c}$ is
$$
X^c_i=\frac{1}{2V}\iint_Sx_i^2n_j\delta_{ij}dS
$$
which is not equal to $$
\frac{1}{2V}\iint_S\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2\right)n_idS
$$

**EDIT**: When revert back, still bewildered by why do we have to apply Gauss' Theorem component-wisely here?

Comment: I thought Gauss's (aka **divergence**) theorem is only applicable when we are integrating __divergence__ of a vector field (which would be __scalar__) over volume. However, you are trying to apply it to the volume integral of a **vector** $\vec{x}$, which you express as _gradient of scalar field_, which is, again, a vector. My conclusion is that ___divergence theorem is not applicable___ in your case.

Comment: They do equal. $\int_S x_i^2 n_j dS = 0$ whenever $i \ne j$.

Comment: @Vlad, there is a simple extension of divergence theorem to vectors.For any scalar function $\phi$ and vector function $\vec{A}$, $\int_V \vec{\nabla} \phi dV = \int_{\partial V} \phi \vec{n} dS$ and $\int_V \vec{\nabla}\times \vec{A} dV = \int_{\partial V} \vec{n} \times \vec{A} dS$.

Comment: @achillehui I did not know that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

As noted by @Vlad you cannot use the divergence theorem because in the integral
$$
{2V}\iiint_V\nabla\left(\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}\right)dV \qquad (1)
$$
you have not a divergence (a scalar) but a gradient (a vector).

So the integral in $(1)$ is really a vector:
$$
\iiint_V\nabla\left(\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}\right)dV=\hat x_1 \iiint_V2x_1dV +\hat x_2 \iiint_V2x_2dV+\hat x_3 \iiint_V2x_3dV
$$

Now you can apply the divergence theorem to the three integrals at the right, where ve have a scalar function such that $2x_i=\frac{d}{dx_i}x_i^2$ .... And you find the correct result.(and this is essentially the generalization suggested by @achillehui).

Comment: Note that Gaussian Gradient Theorem applies to closed surface.

Comment: Sorry the correct should be formally: 
$$
X^c_i=\frac{1}{2V}\iint_Sx_i^2\,n_j\delta_{ij}dS
$$

Answer (score 1):

One should notice that the integrand in the following equation contains dirac delta function,
$$X^c_i=\frac{1}{2V}\iint_Sx_i^2n_j\delta_{ij}dS$$

which suggests that the explicit form of the integral will look like:

$$X^c_i=\frac{1}{2V}\iint_S\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 x_1^2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & x_2^2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & x_3^2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 n_1 \\
 n_2 \\
 n_3 \\
\end{array}
\right)dS$$

$$X^c_i=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 X_1^c \\
 X_2^c \\
 X_3^c \\
\end{array}
\right)=\frac{1}{2V}\iint_S\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 n_1 x_1^2 \\
 n_2 x_2^2 \\
 n_3 x_3^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)dS$$